# Problem with title when adding new articles

Tags: titles, article, metadata, journal-publishing

I'm trying to add several articles in a `documentclass{article}` in order to create a journal.

I have this code in the `\metadata` (before `\begin{document}`) to create a *big title* in the article:

```
% Maketitle metadata 
   \title{\vspace{-15mm}% 
    \fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont
    \textbf{The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy }
    }   
    \author{%
    \large
    \textsc{42}\thanks{Template by \href{http://www.howtotex.com}{UNIVERSE}} \\[2mm]
        \normalsize 42 \\
        \normalsize \href{mailto:frits@howtoTeX.com}{42.com (
        \vspace{-5mm}
        }
        \date{}
```

The result:

[image]

Howewer, when I try to add a *new article*, I don't know how to write the title in the same way again. Copying the code again is not working properly:

```
\clearpage

\maketitle
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    {\vspace{-15mm}%
    \fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont
    \textbf{The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy (BIS)}
}   
\author{%
    \large
    \textsc{42}\thanks{Template by \href{http://www.howtotex.com}{UNIVERSE}} \\[2mm]
    \normalsize 42 \\
    \normalsize \href{mailto:frits@howtoTeX.com}{42.com}
    \vspace{-5mm}
    }
    \date{}

\begin{abstract}
\noindent La Guía del autoestopista galáctico o Guía del viajero intergaláctico (The   
\end{abstract}
```

The result:

[image]

I'm aware that command `\maketitle` works only once in `article`, but I don't know how to solve the problem, maybe you could offer some advice with a different type of `documentclass`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead of your second article.

```
\clearpage

\thispagestyle{fancy}
\vspace{-15mm}%

\begin{center}
\fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont
\textbf{The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy (BIS)}

\large
\textsc{42}\footnote{Template by \href{http://www.howtotex.com}{UNIVERSE}} \\[2mm]
\normalsize 42 \\
\normalsize \href{mailto:frits@howtoTeX.com}{42.com}
\end{center}

\vspace{-5mm}

\begin{abstract}
\noindent La Guía del autoestopista galáctico o Guía del viajero intergaláctico (The   
\end{abstract}
```

This is just typographical code, you can always use it.
Commands like `\maketitle` or `\author` have a specific purpose. Which does not correspond to yours. So it's better not to use them in these cases.

`article` is made to write an article, but you can use it as an advanced typewriter, not involving specific purpose `article`'s commands. They save a lot of work, but they are not good for your purpose. If you use them, you will find yourself needing help very often.

Besides take a look at this class: [ArsTeXnica](http://www.guit.sssup.it/downloads/arstexnica.zip), with template/example [atsample](http://www.guit.sssup.it/download/atsample.tex).
I really cannot find an easier way to write a journal.